# Como puedo descargar todos los archivos en el arreglo?

Tags: c#, array, blob, descarga

Tengo el siguiente arreglo:

```
foreach (string Id in Arguments.SelectedValues)
{
    string temp = @"http://localhost:17277/blob.ashx?Pdf=o|" + Id;
    Result.NavigateUrl = @"http://localhost:17277/blob.ashx?Pdf=o|" + Id;
}
```

en el cual accedo al BLOB donde se encuentra el archivo y lo descarga.
Cuando lo ejecuto, el arreglo si me trae todos los IDs, pero únicamente me descarga el archivo del último ID en el arreglo.

¿A qué se debe y cómo puedo hacer que descargue todos los seleccionados?

Answer (score 1):

Claro esto sucede porque en cada iteracion del for estas pisando el dato previo quedandolo solo el ultimo asignado para navegar

Si en a url puedes definir una lista de Ids entonces deberias unirlos y navegar al final

```
 string Ids = string.Join("|", Arguments.SelectedValues);

 string temp = @"http://localhost:17277/blob.ashx?Pdf=o|" + Ids;

 Result.NavigateUrl = temp;
```

si puedes separar cada id con algun caracter como imagino es el `|` podrias enviar varios ids en la url para que descargue las imagenes,o imagino genere el pdf con las imagenes de esos Ids

Answer (score 1):

Para descargar multiples archivos, podrias hacerlo de varias formas, la primera sera modificar el handler para que reciba los ids a descargar genere un zip y lo retorne para descargar, otra es que el action actual retorne un java script que contenga todos los urls a el handler, en tags `a` con el atributo `target="_blank"`, los cuales por `js` les simulas el click para que asi se inicie la descarga de archivos.

Ejemplo de js

```js
<script>
   jQuery(function(){
      @foreach(var urlArchivo in ViewBag.Archivos)
      {
<text>
      $('body').append($('<a target="_black" href="@urlArchivo" class="archivo-descargar" style="display:none"></a>'));
<text>    
      }
      $(".archivo-descargar").click();
      $(".archivo-descargar").remove();

   });
</script>
```

En el caso del zip existen librerias como `DotNetZip` que facilitan el trabajo de hacer un zip